# Capturar valor variable Javascript en Laravel Route

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Estoy desarrollando una pantalla en que tengo que hacer una redirección después de tocar un botón en jQuery. Sin embargo, a la hora de pasar el parámetro a la route (de Laravel), la pantalla me da error a la hora de crear la URL, ya que la crea de forma literal.

El código del botón en jQuery es el siguiente:

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function(event) {
    var valorId = $('#nId').val();

    window.location.href = '{{ route('usuario.delete', ['id' => '+valorId+'] ) }}';
});
```

Pero el resultante es literal: http://webejemplo.com/usuario/delete/+valorid+

He probado poniendo también un punto en vez de +, y lo mismo...

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function(event) {
    var valorId = $('#nId').val();

    window.location.href = '{{ route('usuario.delete', ['id' => '.valorId.'] ) }}';
});
```

Incluso ya como prueba final, he probado sin poner nada con la variable dentro de las comillas simples del Id, pero entonces ya me da un error de página.

El route de esa dirección es este:

```
Route::post('usuario/delete/{id}', ['uses' => 'UserController@delete', 'as' => 'usuario.delete']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La solución de @Ferran Muñoz es correcta, sin embargo haré unas correcciones con su explicación

```
$('#btnDelete').click(() => {
    var valorId = $('#nId').val();
    //Aqui tomas la route de laravel con un id llamado 'temp'
    //Nota el uso de comillas dobles y simples
    var url = "{{ route('usuario.delete', ['id' => 'temp']) }}";
    //Aqui sustituyes la palabra temp por el valor de valorId
    url = url.replace('temp', valorId);

    location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien, al final lo interesante de todo es pasar un campo "dummy" y luego mediante replace poner el valor que te interesa. Quedaría así:

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function(event) {
    var valorId = $('#nId').val();

    var url = '{!! route('usuario.delete', ['id' => '.valorIdTemp.']) !!}';
    url = replace('/.valorIdTemp./, '/'+valorId);

    window.location.href = url;
});
```